# Remove escape characters

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to remove the escape character from my input XML.Below is my input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AsBuiltWOEstimates_response>
<STATEMENT_TEST_response><xml_response>&lt; header&gt;&lt;wonum&gt;20000000346&lt;/wonum&gt;&lt;success&gt;F&lt;/success&gt;&lt;/header&gt;&lt;error&gt;&lt;line&gt;&lt;/line&gt; &lt;message&gt; LINE 1215 : Sub Account is null or blank : Work Order does not exist : Could not derive Business Segment from WO Header : Sub Account does not exist or is invalid ||&lt;/message&gt;&lt;/error&gt;</xml_response>
</STATEMENT_TEST_response>
</AsBuiltWOEstimates_response>
```

I have tried the XSLT to remove the characters, but while doing so it also removes the XML declaration. Hence  it fails as it does not recognize it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/AsBuiltWOEstimates_response">
<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actual Result -

```
<header>
<wonum>20000000346</wonum>
<success>F</success>
</header><error>
<line></line> 
<message> LINE 1215 : Sub Account is null or blank : Work Order does not exist : Could not derive Business Segment from WO Header : Sub Account does not exist or is invalid ||</message>
</error>
```

Expected Result -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AsBuiltWOEstimates_response>
<STATEMENT_TEST_response>
<header><wonum>20000000346</wonum><success>F</success></header><error><line></line> <message> LINE 1215 : Sub Account is null or blank : Work Order does not exist : Could not derive Business Segment from WO Header : Sub Account does not exist or is invalid ||</message></error>
</STATEMENT_TEST_response>
</AsBuiltWOEstimates_response>
```

Comment: Your stylesheet says `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` - so of course the XML declaration is omitted from the output. Not that it should matter: the XML declaration is optional. Not sure what you mean by *"Hence it fails as it does not recognize it."*

Comment: Thank you michael!! It Worked 
Can you please help me with removing <![CDATA[ and ]]> from the below XML
<xml_response><![CDATA[<header><wonum>20000000346</wonum><success>F</success></header><error><line></line> <message> LINE 1215 : Sub Account is null or blank : Work Order does not exist : Could not derive Business Segment from WO Header : Sub Account does not exist or is invalid ||</message></error>]]></xml_response>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Or ask new questions in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the expected result (approximately, in terms of indenting) you should be doing:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xml_response">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="xml_response">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;', substring-after(., '&lt; '))" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

plz check this code becoz your input space after '< '